# Is there a way to make Safari 4 open requested popups instead of opening new tabs?

Tags: browser, safari, popups

There are several sites I use (such as Tumblr) that use popups to post content. When they open in a new tab, the layout of these little popups is blown up because they fill an entire page.

I've seen other copies of Safari 4 act as expected, but I can't figure out what setting I'm missing. It acts the same way regardless of the "`Block Pop-Up Windows`" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Safari behaves exactly like you want it to do **by default**. There is one switch that controls whether or not content is opened in a new tab. Have you tried this:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari TargetedClicksCreateTabs -bool false
```

Comment: It does sound like the poster has Saft or some other 3rd party plugin that has changed their defaults.

Comment: I have no plugins other than 1Password. I think it might have something to do with having run the Safari 4 beta before the full release version came out (the one with the weird top-tabs).